# Pandas - Ignoring Blank Strings when subtracting two columns

Tags: pandas

I am trying to subtract two columns (Price1 & Price2) that are stored as strings.

I have two data sets, 'data' which has blank strings and 'data2' which does not have blank strings in the price columns. The code works fine on data2 but am trying to get it to work on the regular 'data' set.

The line below is the one that is not working currently. I am trying to have it subtract the two columns only when both Price1 & Price2 are not blank strings. Full code with sample date is below.

```
df['PriceDiff']     = (df['Price1'].astype(float) - df['Price2'].astype(float)).where((~df['Price1'].eq('')) & (~df['Price2'].eq('')), 'Check for Blank Strings in Price Values')
```

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'Product': ['G_FIXED', 'G_FIXED', 'P_FIXED', 'P_FIXED', 'G_FIXED', 'G_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED' ],
        'Price1': ['6.10', '5.70', '6.10', '', '5.10', '4.70', '5.10', '4.70', '10.10', '', '10.10', '3.70'],
        'Price2': ['6.10', '5.70', '', '5.70', '', '4.70', '', '4.70', '9.10', '', '', '8.70']
        }

data2 = {
        'Product': ['G_FIXED', 'G_FIXED', 'P_FIXED', 'P_FIXED', 'G_FIXED', 'G_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED', 'O_FIXED' ],
        'Price1': ['6.10', '5.70', '6.10', '2.35', '5.10', '4.70', '5.10', '4.70', '10.10', '1.00', '10.10', '3.70'],
        'Price2': ['6.10', '2.70', '6.10', '2.35', '8.10', '4.70', '5.10', '4.70', '13.10', '1.00', '10.10', '3.70'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2['PriceDiff2']   = df2['Price1'].astype(float) - df2['Price2'].astype(float)
df2['PriceDiff2-2'] = (df2['Price1'].astype(float) - df2['Price2'].astype(float)).where((~df2['Price1'].eq('')) & (~df2['Price2'].eq('')), 'Check for Blank Strings in Price Values')
df['PriceDiff']     = (df['Price1'].astype(float) - df['Price2'].astype(float)).where((~df['Price1'].eq('')) & (~df['Price2'].eq('')), 'Check for Blank Strings in Price Values')

print(df)
print()
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean mask to keep the right rows:

```
# Find rows where it's possible to compute the diff
m = df[['Price1', 'Price2']].ne('').all(axis=1)

# Compute the diff
df['PriceDiff'] = df.loc[m, ['Price1', 'Price2']].astype(float) \
                    .agg('diff', axis=1)['Price2'].reindex(df.index, fill_value='')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Product Price1 Price2 PriceDiff
0   G_FIXED   6.10   6.10       0.0
1   G_FIXED   5.70   5.70       0.0
2   P_FIXED   6.10                 
3   P_FIXED          5.70          
4   G_FIXED   5.10                 
5   G_FIXED   4.70   4.70       0.0
6   O_FIXED   5.10                 
7   O_FIXED   4.70   4.70       0.0
8   O_FIXED  10.10   9.10      -1.0
9   O_FIXED                        
10  O_FIXED  10.10                 
11  O_FIXED   3.70   8.70       5.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Though I would like to understand why my method did not work, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Your method doesn't work because your first operation `(df['Price1'].astype(float) - df['Price2'].astype(float))` is not possible. Your 2 columns can't be converted to float because empty string have no equivalent to float.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the ".where()" portion of that line only passed the lines where both columns had a float value

Comment: No, the problem is before. The result will be passed to `where` if an exception is not raised before.